# how to check if already login into siteminder

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, siteminder

Is there a way to check from .net if user already log in to site-minder protected resource? if so, get some header information. My goal is to find out if i am already have a site-minder session.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, if you have SiteMinder protecting your application the only way the HTTP request would reach the application code is if the Siteminder agent in front of it has validated the request.

You can check for the presence of the **SM_USER** request header in your application. It is enabled by default and all SiteMinder protected resources receive this header in the request.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure SiteMinder agent to insert headers in HTTP request coming into .NET.  Check for the presence of this header, if it is there, that means the user is authenticated.  I believe there are also SMIDENTITY and SMSESSION cookies being passed in as well.  Check with your SiteMinder support guys, you can also just put together a simple page that returns all header and cookies and compare the outcome with SiteMinder session and without.

Answer (score 0):

SiteMinder will indeed add a cookie with the name SMSESSION and a value which is used as an SSO token for the duration of the session. If you need to count on this value for authentication, however, you must verify it (anybody could add a cookie to the request and pass it to you). SiteMider's SDK provides an AgentApi class that can do this for you. What you do is decode the token then recreate the user credential. You will need to have the ip address of the Policy Server that originally issued the token as well as the agent name and its credentials. At the link provided pay particular attention to the decodeSSOToken, isProtected and login methods. Good luck.

https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%2012%2052-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/programming-reference/legacy-sm-java-sdk/netegrity/siteminder/javaagent/AgentAPI.html